# What command: start in docker-compose is doing?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose [file](https://github.com/openimis/openimis-dist_dkr/blob/main/docker-compose.yml) for many images.

Here is a part that I am interested in.

```
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: https://github.com/openimis/openimis-be_py.git
    image: openimis/backend:${PROJECT_NAME:-local}
    command: start
```

Here is [Dockerfile](https://github.com/openimis/openimis-be_py/blob/main/Dockerfile).

I am sorry I didn't copy-paste too detailed file here to not make the question too confusing.

Issue is that I able to up and run app via docker-compose, but when I am trying to run single `backend` container it stops too fast.

I suspect the issue is with `command: start` part.
Can you please advice me what command is doing and how to update Dockerfile to run single container.

Comment: Try removing that line. There’s an entry point already

Comment: I tried. In this case I can't run app even with docker-compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `command` is:

- [either executed at container startup](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) (if no `entrypoint` exists), or
- [passed along as argument to the `entrypoint`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint) (if an `entrypoint` exists).

In the given example, [the `Dockerfile` in the git repository mentioned (`github.com`)](https://github.com/openimis/openimis-be_py/blob/main/Dockerfile) defines an `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["/openimis-be/script/entrypoint.sh"]
```

So the `command`-value (`start`) will be passed as argument to the [`entrypoint.sh`-script (`github.com`)](https://github.com/openimis/openimis-be_py/blob/main/script/entrypoint.sh).